# How can I make a sticky/fixed side nav like this one in the attached pic?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, google-web-designer

In the pic I have attached, when I click on any item in the left side nav menu, the page in the right loads but the menu remains fixed and does not load. 
How can I make a menu like this? 
Can I do it using div? or Do I need to use 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kUBP.png)

Comment: **Sorry for the incomplete description. I am new here** In the pic I have attached, when I click on any item in the left side nav menu, the page in the right loads but the menu remains fixed and does not load. How can I make a menu like this? Can I do it using div? or Do I need to use <frame>

Comment: That seems to be a react website, here you can find some [examples](https://it.reactjs.org/community/examples.html) and [here](https://reactjsexample.com/tag/sidebar/) others